# How to make my collectionView extend below an opaque tabBar

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I am hiding my navigation bar and tab bar when I scroll.

`extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` is set to true.

The scrollView extend below the Tab Bar alright.

The problem is that when the navigation bar and tab bar becomes hidden, the collectionView (a ASCollectionNode actually) expands to make up for the navigation bar height. You can see the extra cells appears and looks odd.

How can I force the extended layout to render further below?

**Edit: more explanation**

```
A NavBar
B 1 1 1
C 2 2 2 
D 3 3 3
E 4 4 4
F 5 5 5
G TabBar
```

row [6 6 6] is already rendered and hidden under the TabBar thanks to extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars

User scrolls and both NavBar and TabBar becomes hidden and everything shift up as it should:

```
A 1 1 1 
B 2 2 2 
C 3 3 3
D 4 4 4
F 5 5 5
G 6 6 6
H 7 7 7
```

The problem is that if the user scroll really fast... You can see the [7 7 7] appearing in a funky way. A quick solution would be to disable the animation of the tab bar hiding down but I don't really want to do that.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to extend the scrollview below the Tab Bar so that when the view extends to fill the space occupied by the navigation bar, row H is already rendered.

Comment: gonna have to include screenshots and code to show what's happening,

Comment: maybe a video would help...

Comment: Added some ascii art

Comment: create a blank(empty) view and use(set) it as header and footer view of the collection view.

Comment: I don't see how that would help... I want the cells to extend below the tabbar and visible screen